# How to configure Symfony2 and Assetic settings for custom filters [Bootstrap, JQuery]?

Tags: node.js, symfony, less, assetic, yui-compressor

I've been working on Symfony2 and some problems appeared with Assetic compilers and filters. 
Does anyone knows how to make it work on Windows platform, because almost every example responds to *nix environments?

Does routes to `.exe` should have the format: 
`C:\\....\\`, in order to get done the access to: `Java.exe`, `Node.exe`

*nix has its paths as: `/usr/bin/local`

Or as Symfony style: `/../../`

Which is the right option to accept?

Comment: None, just gaining time and sharing

Comment: @Félix You can share the knowledge in this way on Stack Overflow, but the site format should still be considered. Reformulate this as a question and put the solution part into an answer.

Comment: Question and answer built. Thanks for your help to make this article better.

Answer (score 1):

These are the settings that worked for me on:

1. Windows **8.1 (x64)**
2. PhpStorm **8.0**
3. NodeJs **v0.10.35**
4. Symfony **2.7** (recently updated)

---

I want to share it with everyone else.
These were of great help to achieve the result:

[Use Twitter Bootstrap in Symfony2 with Composer](https://coderwall.com/p/kzyiaw/use-twitter-bootstrap-in-symfony2-with-composer)

[Symfony 2 and Bootstrap 3 Assetic Config and Base HTML Template](http://mossco.co.uk/symfony-2/symfony-2-and-bootstrap-3-assetic-config-and-base-html-template-file/)

[Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons font's not found when using assetic in prod on Symfony2](http://www.widecodes.com/CiVVXVWqgk/twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons-fonts-not-found-when-using-assetic-in-prod-on-symfony2.html)

---

## composer.json

```
    "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
    "bmatzner/jquery-ui-bundle": "*",
    "bmatzner/jquery-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.0"  (note: optional)
```

---

## parameters.yml

```
#Assetic parameters

java_dir: "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_40\\bin\\java.exe"
node_dir: "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
node_modules: "C:\\Users\\fraballi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"
yui_jar: "%kernel.root_dir%\Resources\java\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"
cssembed: "%kernel.root_dir%\Resources\java\cssembed-0.4.5.jar"
less_php: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php"
```

---

## config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration

assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
java: %java_dir%"
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    less:
        node: %node_dir%
        node_paths: [%node_modules%]
        apply_to:   "\.less$"
    yui_css:
        jar: "%yui_jar%"
    yui_js:
        jar: "%yui_jar%"
    cssembed:
        jar: "%cssembed%"
assets:
    jquery_js:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bmatzner/jquery-bundle/Bmatzner/JQueryBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
        filters: [?yui_js]
    bootstrap_js:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/affix.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/alert.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/button.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/modal.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/popover.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tab.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js'
        filters: [?yui_js]
    bootstrap_less:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
        filters: [less]
    bootstrap_fonts_woff:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    bootstrap_fonts_ttf:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    bootstrap_fonts_svg:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    bootstrap_fonts_eot:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

---

## commands

```
php app/console --env=dev cache:clear
php app/console --env=dev cache:clear --no-debug
php app/console --env=dev assets:install web --no-debug
php app/console --env=dev assetic:dump --no-debug
```

---

## Twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets '@bootstrap_less' combine=true %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@jquery_js' '@bootstrap_js' filter='?yui_js' combine=true %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```